# Как определиться с расстановкой дефисов

Tags: орфография

Попалось в одной рукописи, но у меня вызывает сомнение правильность расстановки дефисов. А именно "псевдо-карден" и "лже-Ив-Сен-Лоран". Речь, понятно, идет о вещах, выдаваемых за продукцию фирм Кардена и Ив-Сен Лорана (честно говоря, не знаю, как его имя правильно пишется, так что, если что, поправьте). Но как в данном случае написать? Если слитно, то в случае с Карденом это еще понятно, но как быть со вторым кутюрье? А если через дефис, то еще непонятнее.
Какие будут варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, правильно: псевдо-Карден, лже Ив Сен-Лоран, но я приведу
более понятное объяснение.

Здесь действуют корректирующие правила Лопатина http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80

1) псевдо-Карден: обычно слитное написание форманта  "псевдо" заменяется дефисным написанием перед ПРОПИСНОЙ БУКВОЙ.

2) лже Ив Сен-Лоран: обычно СЛИТНОЕ написание форманта "лже" заменяется РАЗДЕЛЬНЫМ написанием перед словосочетанием с РАЗДЕЛЬНЫМ написанием Ив + Сен-Лоран.

3) лже-Сен-Лоран: обычно СЛИТНОЕ написание форманта "лже" заменяется ДЕФИСНЫМ написанием написанием перед ДЕФИСНЫМ написанием Сен-Лоран.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

*псевдо-Карден, лже Ив Сен-Лоран.*

Начальная составная часть *псевдо*- пишется слитно, но с именами собственными - через дефис, так как недопустимы слитные написания с одной прописной буквой в середине слова.

Недопустимо слитное написание и если вторая часть содержит дефис или пробел, тогда ставится второй дефис или пробел (теле-ток-шоу, лже Ван Гог).

Пробел ближе к *лже*-, чем дефис, поэтому именно пробел диктует раздельное написание. Иначе было бы *лже-Сен-Лоран*.